# Como faço para alterar o incremento de um botão atraves de outro botão?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Tenho um botão que soma uma variável: `x + 1`, e sempre que clico nesse botão, a variável vai aumentar 1 unidade.

Mas como eu faço para programar um botão para alterar a função do botão 1, para que em vez de `x + 1`, seja `x + 2`

Os botões, e tudo isso, estam sendo programados em `Java JFrame` com o programa `netBeans`.

```
private int xi;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



    xi++;
    jLabel2.setText("Your money  " + xi + "$");

}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //E neste butao que quero fazer a funcao.


}
```

Comment: Adicione como está sua tentativa de código até agora na pergunta.

Comment: Olha jovem, isso depende. Se for apenas mudar a quantidade incrementada de **`1`** para **`2`**, eu usaria uma variável que define esta quantidade e alteraria o valor dela. Agora, se você quer mudar toda a função, aí é outra história.

Comment: @jbueno não é muito complicado, na verdade, eu já até tenho uma sugestao melhor aqui em mente, mas preciso ver o código dele antes, pra depois não ter que ficar adaptando toda hora.

Comment: Sim, eu sei que é simples.

Comment: Pronto esta aqui uma amostra do codigo

Comment: A variação é só de +1 pra +2? Se for só isso, da pra fazer usando togglebutton

Comment: Ok, vou explicar um pouco mais o que eu quero fazer. Eu quero fazer um joguinho onde, ao clicar no button1 voce vai ganhar mais 1$. Ai, voce pode comprar um"upgrade" onde vai custar 150$ para que, ao clicar no button2, voce ganha +2 por clique. Por isso nao posso usar togglebutton porque voce so pode comprar 1 vez.

Comment: A situação que você está explicando pode ser feita com 2 botoes diferentes, mas na pergunta você quer fazer com o mesmo.

Comment: Sm! Basicamente, eu tenho o botao1 fazendo uma funcao. Depois, eu quero que, ao clicar no botao2, eu quero que ele mude de funcao, para que em vez de somar 1, some 2.

Comment: Se for pra somar de 2 em 2, basta  usar `xi += 2;` ao inves de `xi++` no segundo botao. É isso?

Comment: Nao é bem isso que eu quero fazer. Eu quero que ao clicar no botão 2, o butao1 vai começar somando 2 na variável xi.   O botao2 é apenas utilizado para alterar a função do botao1 e nao é mais utilizado.

Comment: A idéia é a mesma que eu disse, só que com uma variavel a mais para controlar o incremento, ao inves de fazer com o operador `++`. O botão 2 só poderá ser acionado uma vez?

Comment: Sim, o botao 2 so é acionado 1 vez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de fazer isso seria utilizando uma variável exclusiva para representar o "incremento":

```
private int xi = 1;
private int increment = 1;
```

Depois, no primeiro botão, você altera para o seguinte:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    xi += increment;
    jLabel2.setText("Your money  " + xi + "$");

}
```

E no segundo botão:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    increment = 2;//ou increment++;
    //desativa o botao apos o primeiro uso
    ((JButton) evt.getSource()).setEnable(false); 

}
```

Da forma como está, nem precisa desativar o botão, pois por mais que se clique nele, a alteração sempre será para 2. Se usar `increment++`, é preciso usar o código que desativa o botão para parar o incremento.

Comment: tava comentando isso, foi mal!

Comment: @ThomasBrazPinto não entendi.

Comment: Infelizmente esta me dando algum tipo de erro no "xi+increment;". A hint do erro diz "not a statement".

Comment: @GuilhermeFigueira corrigido, errinho de incremento no button1.

Comment: Muito obrigado @diegofm finalmente deu certo!

Comment: é que eu comentei exatamente a mesma coisa que você (ou quase) mas enquanto eu tava digitando, você respondeu e eu não vi, por isso falei

Answer (score 2):

cara, você pode usar uma variável pra fazer isso! é bem simples:

```
private int xi;
private int xi2=1;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    xi+=xi2;
    jLabel2.setText("Your money  " + xi + "$");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    xi2+=1;//aqui você muda o tanto que vale, é só adicionar mais um, no caso depende do que você quer adicionar,
    //se você mudar o valor aqui, pode colocar + 150 até, que aí a cada clique vai adicionar + 150
}
```